# from ..layers import Input SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to run resnet50.py from keras.applications  but i get this error:

```
    from ..layers import Input
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

pls tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that resnet50.py is a part of the keras package and is not meant to be run as a standalone script by itself.

I would recommend importing the relevant classes from the resnet50 package. For example, you could do something like:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

resnet = ResNet50(...)
```

Of course, you would need to install keras first.